# Junit tests fail with mvn clean install for aspectj decorated classes

Tags: java, maven, junit, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am trying to use aspectj-metrics for metering/timing my non resource methods. E.g:

```
@Metrics(registry = "metric-registry")
public class CustomStage extends BaseStage<ABC,DEF> {

    // ....

    @Override
    @Timed(name = "metricName")
    public String applyRowFunction(ABC dataRow) {
         // ...
        return dataRow;
    }

}
```

The unit test for this class is as follows (JUNIT):

```
@Test
    public void testStage() throws Exception {
        // ...
SharedMetricRegistries.add("metric-registry", reg);

        ConsoleReporter.forRegistry(reg)
                .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .outputTo(new PrintStream(System.out))
                .build()
                .start(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        CustomStage stage = new CustomeStage(...);
        // ...
}
```

But the unit test fails with mvn clean install at the line where i am constructing the instance. What am i missing? I've tried searching for examples but no avail.

I am using aspectj-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>io.astefanutti.metrics.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>metrics-aspectj</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                    <sources/>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <weaveDirectories>
                                <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
                            </weaveDirectories>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <weaveDirectories>
                                <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</weaveDirectory>
                            </weaveDirectories>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: How is your test failing?  What's the stack/error?  Does your test work if you run from IDE?

Comment: If you do not answer any questions, nobody can help you...